# Skip a hierarchy when deserialising with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

Let's suppose we have a json like this one, that cannot be modified.
And we want do deserilise it using Gson.

```
{
  "user": {
    "some_ids": {
      "useless_key": [
        "22a074ff-91bf-4599-9a9e-374d3f01b6e0",
        "66c8ce85-f162-4d92-a836-198a17764efa",
        "d0519a9e-bfa2-446c-bb98-746136a3e513"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We want to deserialise it in a class `User` like this one:

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("some_ids")
    List<String> someIds;
}
```

**The question:**
The simple solution would be to create a `UselessKey` wrapper class and put the `someIds` list in it.

But is there a way to tell Gson to skip the node `useless_key`and directly deserialise the List inside `someIds` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you still have to mark a field supposed to be processed differently, Gson does not provide anything like that. However you can implement such behavior. The closest thing to your request is `@JsonAdapter`

Suppose you have

```java
private static final String JSON = "{\n"
        + "  \"user\": {\n"
        + "    \"some_ids\": {\n"
        + "      \"useless_key\": [\n"
        + "        \"22a074ff-91bf-4599-9a9e-374d3f01b6e0\",\n"
        + "        \"66c8ce85-f162-4d92-a836-198a17764efa\",\n"
        + "        \"d0519a9e-bfa2-446c-bb98-746136a3e513\"\n"
        + "      ]\n"
        + "    }\n"
        + "  }\n"
        + "}";

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Response response = gson.fromJson(JSON, Response.class);
    out.println(response.getUser().getSomeIds());
}
```

The DTO `Response` class is defined as the follows:

```java
final class Response {

    private Response() { }

    @SerializedName("user")
    private final User user = null;

    User getUser() { return user; }

    static final class User {

        private User() { }

        @SerializedName("some_ids")
        @JsonAdapter(IdsTypeAdapter.class)
        private final List<String> someIds = null;

        List<String> getSomeIds() { return someIds; }

    }

}
```

The type adapter specified in `@JsonAdapter(IdsTypeAdapter.class)` above can be implemented as follows:

```java
final class IdsTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<List<String>> {

    private static final String USELESS_PROPERTY = "useless_key";

    private IdsTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter writer, final List<String> value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> read(final JsonReader reader)
            throws IOException {
        reader.beginObject();
        if ( !reader.nextName().equals(USELESS_PROPERTY) ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expected: " + USELESS_PROPERTY);
        }
        reader.beginArray();
        final List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( reader.peek() == STRING ) {
            ids.add(reader.nextString());
        }
        reader.endArray();
        reader.endObject();
        return unmodifiableList(ids);
    }

}
```

The type adapter above is pretty easy, and promotes stream reading in order to improve performance (type adapters are also required by the `@JsonAdapter` annotation). And the result:

> [22a074ff-91bf-4599-9a9e-374d3f01b6e0, 66c8ce85-f162-4d92-a836-198a17764efa, d0519a9e-bfa2-446c-bb98-746136a3e513]

Another option is use of JSON deserializers (can be registered in `GsonBuilder`), but the latter have performance impacts since they require the whole JSON tree to be built before a deserialization process begins. Another issue with JSON deserializers is that Gson does not support custom annotations, so in order to mark "special" fields you still need to create a wrapper class like `class StringIds extends ArrayList<String>` that later would even require a deserialization context to deserialize a given `JsonElement` to `List<String>` and then remapped back to `StringIds`. That's expensive. I would go with type adapters.

Answer (score -1):

Just don't create the variable and getter and setter in your Model class. It will not then parse the key which is not found.

Comment: Won't it simply skip the whole data inside the key as well and I guess the question here needs to have that data parsed too?